# PyCharm - Python error while updating skeletons

Tags: python, pycharm

https://pastebin.com/0Snv5tr5

```
There is no code, just trying to paste a dump here.
```

Pastebin dump report.

Windows gives a "Python stopped working" error (with a option to send a report) while PyCharm is updating its skeletons.

I updated to the current version of Java today, but IDK how that could reflect on that. Maybe PyCharm has some dependency on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to uninstall pyQt in my Python environment.